# rails multiple joins and functions

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have this sql:

```
select al.name, date_trunc('day', rc.start_date) as d, min(rc.start_date)
from 
records rc inner join relations rl 
on rl.record_id=rc.id 
inner join
aliases al on rl.alias_id=al.id
where rc.user_id=2 and ( al.contact_id<>2 or al.contact_id is null)
group by al.name, d
order by d DESC
```

And models:

```
class Alias < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contact
  has_many :relations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :records, :through => :relations 
  belongs_to :user
end

class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :relations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :aliases, :through => :relations
  belongs_to :user
end

class Relation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :record
  belongs_to :alias
end

class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :aliases
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :aliases
  has_many :contacts
  has_many :records
end
```

How do I write sql query presented in rails manner?

Comment: To get a specific answer, you'll need to add your User and Contact models, both of which are referenced in your SQL.  It would also be helpful if you could describe in words what you are trying to do (which will make the rails query more obvious, since the rails query will be closer to the natural language description of what you are trying to do).

Comment: I agree with Marc.  One other comment, whether SQL or Rails, you are asking for trouble having three models each of whose names use reserved words from either SQL or Rails, or both.  Is there any way you could change these to make them more semantically meaningful in the context of your application?

Comment: Ok I added User and Contact models. Some more description: i have system which records some "records" related to Contacts. Contact can be defined in many ways and that is reason to create "alias" which can be in relation to Contact. There might be thousands of records daily. I want to create some list, where those thousands would be grouped by days in some packages, to easily track "records". I'm considering if there shouldn't be separate model to aggregate packs of "records" in groups by day. I hope description is clear enough :)

Comment: And regarding names, yes I had some issues with those already, but those names are most meaningful for my application so for now it has to stay. But you are right, and in future i'll change it.